# How to show a UIPickerView using Monotouch Dialog?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a requirement that the user needs to select a category followed by a subcategory. Normally I would use two UIPickerViews to perform the selection. How would you do this with Monotouch Dialog? I cannot find any examples or built in elements anywhere that perform this.

Comment: Did you ever build your own UIPickerView element like miguel suggested? If so, could you share your code for it, I'm having some trouble with mine.

Comment: I have not had enough time to get this right as yet. MonoTouch dialog could do with some enhancements regarding UIPickerViews to make our lives easier...

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own custom element that then renders a UIPicker.   You can see how to build your own custom element in the source code for MonoTouch.Dialog.

Here is one sample:

https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs#L1132